# Is there a bipartite graph with $\sqrt{2}$ as an eigenvalue with high multiplicity, specifically more than in the Heawood graph?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

The [Heawood graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_graph) is a $3$-regular graph on $14$ vertices. Its (adjacency) spectrum is $\{ (3)^1, (\sqrt{2})^6, (-\sqrt{2})^6, (-3)^1 \}$. So, $3/7 \approx 42.8\%$ of its eigenvalues equal $\sqrt{2}$.

Is there a bipartite graph (on any number of vertices) with a greater proportion of eigenvalues as $\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 10):

This is a limited partial answer to the question ruling out the case where the graph is regular and has four distinct eigenvalues, so the spectrum is $\{k, (\sqrt{2})^a, (-\sqrt{2})^a, -k\}$.

van Dam's paper ["Regular Graphs with Four Eigenvalues"](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(94)00346-F) quotes a result that a bipartite regular graph with four distinct eigenvalues is necessarily the incidence graph of a symmetric $2$-$(v,k,\lambda)$ design and that such a graph has spectrum

$$
\left\{k, \left(\sqrt{k-\lambda}\right)^{v-1}, \left(-\sqrt{k-\lambda}\right)^{v-1},-k\right\}.
$$

So we are interested in the case $k-\lambda = 2$.

Now a $2$-$(v,k,\lambda)$ design has
$$
\frac{v(v-1)\lambda}{k(k-1)} = v
$$ blocks and so $(v-1)\lambda = (\lambda+2)(\lambda+1)$ or
$$
v = \frac{\lambda^2+4\lambda+2}{\lambda}.
$$

This only has integral solutions if $\lambda \mid 2$ and so we either have $\lambda = 1$ in which case $v=7$ and we have the $2$-$(7,3,1)$ design (Fano plane) whose incidence graph is the Heawood graph or $\lambda = 2$ in which case we again have $v=7$ and the $2$-$(7,4,2)$ design whose blocks are the complements of the blocks of the Fano plane and which leads to a $4$-regular distance-regular graph again on $14$ vertices and so it has the same proportion of eigenvalues equal to $\pm \sqrt{2}$ as the Heawood graph.

Of course this leaves open non-regular graphs and graphs with more than four distinct eigenvalues but it closes off one narrow avenue of possibility.